# How can I tie togeather extra space on Macintosh desktops with a distributed filesystem?

Tags: macos, filesystems, distributed

I have access to a bunch of Mac desktops, the hard drives of which are under-utilized. I want to set up a distributed filesystem to gang them together into one large virtual volume. The server has to be able to run as a normal user.

I've tried [PVFS2](http://www.pvfs.org/), but it's designed for Linux and isn't running well on OSX (hangs the clients on write).

What should I use instead?

Comment: Very interesting question, but probably belongs on serverfault.com or superuser.com unless your real question is about how to write a distributed file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Andrew File System (AFS) is a very mature distributed file system with OS X support. Check out [OpenAFS](http://www.openafs.org/macos.html).

Comment: It seems like AFS can only be run as root. Is that the case?

Comment: I suspect the AFS daemon must be run as root (I would setup a launchd item to run it), but I recall that you can access the AFS filesystem from other users, given appropriate permissions and configuration. I haven't used AFS since the late 90s, so I can't give you details.